# Is it possible to use EL in ui:repeat?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el, uirepeat

Mojarra 2.1.29

I've read that usually it's not necessary to use `EL` to generate `id`-attribute dynamically. I also know that the id-attribute resolved at `view-building` phase. But in our projects we have to write some Selenium tests which are goign to use some html-attribute in the generated markup. So, I decided to specify the id-attribute dynamically. How can I do that for the following `<ui:repeat>`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean{

    private List<Integer> values;
    //GET, SET
    public Bean(){
        values = Arrays.asList(1,2,5,7,8,9);
    }
}
```

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.values}" var="value">
    <h:outputText id="#{value}" /> <!-- not legal, resolved to null -->
</ui:repeat>
```

Maybe I should specify another attribute fo Selenium instead?

Comment: do you have the name attribute generated? if so you can use the name attribute instead of the id

Comment: also you can try id="value #{value}", it might be illegal to have a digit as an id

Comment: @aurelius It doesn't work

Comment: id attribute cannot have deferred EL as it is generated at view build time and not render time. This is default JSF behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a fixed `id` like the following.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.values}" var="value">
    <h:outputText id="elementId" />
</ui:repeat>
```

The element you need will have `id`s generated as,

```
parentId:0:elementId
parentId:1:elementId
parentId:2:elementId
```

and so on.